# HTML: defining relative paths relative to another file

Tags: html

**Question:** How would I construct relative paths in HTML relative to a different file than that I am working in?

**Purpose:** The navigation menu is ported to each page using the PHP include function. This, however, destroys the relative links embedded in the menu.

Comment: Can you be bit more explanatory? With examples?

Comment: why not start with a base path to avoid any ambiguities ?